# How do I open a WPF menu at design-time?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, styles, design-time

I'm styling a menu in WPF and would like to see how it looks, without having to launch the application to open the menu.

Is there a way to keep the menu open (so I can see the menu items) at design-time, so I can see the changes as I go?

I currently only have Visual Studio 2010 to work with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set IsSubmenuOpen="True", but if you click somewhere else, menu will close. Set it again to open.

Comment: Good tip. It get's us halfway there, but I'd hoped to somehow force it to remain open - even if I click somewhere else. I'll hold the "Answered"-tag a litte while to see if anyone else has a suggestion.

Comment: You can also use KaXaml to design your GUI. It allows you interract with run-time result. Make changes, parse (default auto parse), go to result, click to menu open. You don't need to compile and run whole project in this way.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to see changes in the design window as soon as you make changes - are you using VS2010 express? I found that in express the designer didn't refresh when I made style changes - I had to close/re-open the form to see the changes reflected. You shouldn't need to build to see design changes unless of course you are adding new user controls etc that need to be built before the designer can process them

Comment: The studio updates, but I still can't see what I've done unless the menu is open - showing the menuitems. That's the issue: How do I open the menu at design-time?

Comment: Ah I see what you mean now - I don't think you can keep it open as it will be based on Popup, but if you are declaring it in line in the XAML you can usually just set IsOpen to false then true again and the menu pops open so you can check the changes before you build