# WPF sub menuitem do not show up in the XAML Editor

Tags: c#, wpf, menu, menuitem

I created a `Menu` and inserted a `MenuItem`. For this `MenuItem`, I created 3 sub `MenuItems`.

When I select a sub `MenuItem`, it does not show up in the XAML editor.

```xml
<Window x:Class="CharakterTool3.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CharakterTool3"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <StackPanel>
        <Menu>
            <MenuItem Header="File">
                <MenuItem Header="Open"/>
                <MenuItem Header="Close"/>
                <MenuItem Header="Exit"/>
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

[This is what I expected:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWPmB.png)

[In my Editor, it do not show up:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LoLgM.png)

[During the runtime, it is selectable:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufcFY.png)

I installed Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.9.3
with Microsoft .NET Framework Version 4.8.04084.

What is the source of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

This question already has answers here:

[How do I open a WPF menu at design-time?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10717021/8910867)

> You can set `IsSubmenuOpen="True"`, but if you click somewhere else, menu will close. Set it again to open.

Comment: Tank you for your answere. This does not solve my Problem.
I expanded the code like this:

<MenuItem Header="File" IsSubmenuOpen="True">
                <MenuItem Header="Open" IsSubmenuOpen="True"/>

The Example of my first posted picture do not have the line IsSubmenuOpen="True" and the menu do show up.

Comment: If you set the IsSubmenuOpen property to true, the menu is temporarily visible in the XAML Designer, and if you click anywhere else, the menu disappears again. There is still no way to make it appear permanent.

Comment: Thank you for your answere. I learned something new. In the first posted picture it appears permanently. It seems that using IsSubmenuOpen="True is not the solution.